# Finding a plane perpendicular to two lines and a point

Tags: vectors, cross-product

A plane is perpendicular to both [x,y,z] = [1, -10, 8] + s[1, 2, -1] and

[x,y,z] = [2, 5, -5] + t[2, 1, -3], and contains the point P(-1, 4, -2). Determine

if the point A(7, 10, 16) is also on this plane.

- I can't figure this one out. A vector perpendicular to the two lines found by cross product is [-5,1,0], but a plane requires two vectors. Can someone give me an insight as to how this problem can be solved? Thanks.

Comment: You know one point on the plane in question. Call a second point $Q(x,y,z)$. Then the dot product of the vector $PQ$ and $[-5,1,0]$ must be zero and that will give you the equation.

Comment: Recheck your cross-product.

Answer (score 1):

I only just now realized that you said perpendicular rather than parallel.
 A plane cannot be perpendicular to two lines going in **different** directions.

This problem only makes sense if the plane is parallel to the two given lines. Then the normal vector is

$[1,2,-1]\times[2,1,-3]=[-5,1,-3]$

and the equation of the plane is

$-5(x+1)+(y-4)-3(z+2)=0$

$5x-y+3z=-5$

$5(7)-10+3(16)\ne-5$

Therefore the point $A$ does not lie on the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Since the plane is perpendicular to the given lines, then the direction vector of these lines are normal to the plane. Take, for instance, the vector $\vec{N} = (1,2,-1)$. We know the point $P(-1,4,-2)$ lies in the plane. Pick arbitrary $X(x,y,z)$ in our plane. Then, the equation of our plane is given by

$$ \vec{N} \cdot \vec{PX} = 0 \iff (1,2,-1)\cdot(x+1,y-4,z+2)=0$$

Which is equivalent to $x+2y-z-11=0$. Now, $7+2(10)-16-11 = 0$, which means that the point $(7,10,16)$ lies in the plane.

Comment: You intended to write $x+2y-z-9=0$, but notice that this plane is not perpendicular to the second line which has direction vector $[2,1,-3]$. The problem is obviously misstated and the plane is parallel to both the lines, not perpendicular.